# How to bulk edit bid adjustments for campaign ad schedule using Google Ads Script?

Tags: google-ads-api, google-ads-script

I have a bunch of campaigns that I want to bulk edit ad schedule bid adjustments. How can I achieve that using Google Ads Script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a Google Ads script that takes an array of campaign IDs and sets bid adjustment as **+1%** for a given list of campaigns:

```js
function main() {
  var CAMPAIGN_IDS = [INSERT_YOUR_CAMPAIGN_IDS]; // Replace with your Campaign IDs

  // Define time intervals
  var timeIntervals = [
    {startHour: 0, startMinute: 0, endHour: 4, endMinute: 0},   // 00:00 - 04:00
    {startHour: 4, startMinute: 0, endHour: 8, endMinute: 0},   // 04:00 - 08:00
    {startHour: 8, startMinute: 0, endHour: 12, endMinute: 0},  // 08:00 - 12:00
    {startHour: 12, startMinute: 0, endHour: 16, endMinute: 0}, // 12:00 - 16:00
    {startHour: 16, startMinute: 0, endHour: 20, endMinute: 0}, // 16:00 - 20:00
    {startHour: 20, startMinute: 0, endHour: 24, endMinute: 0}  // 20:00 - 24:00
  ];

  // Define days of the week
  var daysOfWeek = [
    "MONDAY", "TUESDAY", "WEDNESDAY", "THURSDAY", 
    "FRIDAY", "SATURDAY", "SUNDAY"
  ];

  // Loop through each campaign ID
  for (var campaignIndex = 0; campaignIndex < CAMPAIGN_IDS.length; campaignIndex++) {
    var campaignId = CAMPAIGN_IDS[campaignIndex];

    // Retrieves the campaign by its ID.
    var campaignIterator = AdsApp.campaigns()
                           .withIds([campaignId])
                           .get();
    
    if (campaignIterator.hasNext()) {
      var campaign = campaignIterator.next();
      
      // Loop through each day of the week
      for (var dayIndex = 0; dayIndex < daysOfWeek.length; dayIndex++) {
        // Loop through each time interval and set bid adjustment
        for (var timeIndex = 0; timeIndex < timeIntervals.length; timeIndex++) {
          var timeInterval = timeIntervals[timeIndex];

          campaign.addAdSchedule({
            dayOfWeek: daysOfWeek[dayIndex],
            startHour: timeInterval.startHour, 
            startMinute: timeInterval.startMinute, 
            endHour: timeInterval.endHour, 
            endMinute: timeInterval.endMinute, 
            bidModifier: 1.01 // 1% bid adjustment
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note: You need to update the `bidModifier` value depending on your case.
Once you set the script, you can determine its frequency.